# How to reinstall apt on Debian?

Tags: debian, apt

I accidently removed apt-get from my Debian system by issuing:

```
dpkg --force-depends --purge apt
```

How can I reinstall it?

Comment: This is why the `--force-*` options should only be used exceptionally sparingly, even if you think you know what you're doing... Speaking of which, *why* did you feel the need to remove apt?

Comment: apt didnt work any more... I tried to install anything but it didn't work, I got some strange errors. (can't remember which one, I think it said something like "E:small apt database, try to increase the cache" or something) I reinstalled apt and it works now.

Answer (score 15):

ok, I reinstalled it! just downloaded the [deb package](https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=amd64&keywords=apt)
and used dpkg to install it.:

```
dpkg -i apt_0.7.20.2+lenny2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. Could you maybe share the dpkg command used, please?

Comment: Did you use `dpkg -i foobar.deb`?

Comment: I just edited my answer and added the dpkg command.

Comment: That link is broken now. But you can still find the list of available apt distributions by going [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=amd64&keywords=apt)

Comment: @Greg After almost three years, I've now edited the answer to include the correct link.

Answer (score 3):

This link has debian packages for all apt versions that were in a Debian release:
ftp://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/

First install `libapt-pkg` for the version you need and then install the `apt` package for your system using `dpkg -i`.

In case of conflicts, look for `apt` packages in `dpkg -l` and uninstall it using `dpkg -r`. After this use the above step to reinstall `apt`.

Comment: I edited it from Ubuntu to the Debian URL. "All known apt versions" is not true.

Comment: In case of conflicts, it means you installed the wrong version of something. Don't uninstall what's already there, instead install the correct version of what was removed.