# Deleted /etc/apt, now apt-get gives a relocation error?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, linux-mint, apt

I was trying to delete the `sources.list` file for `apt`. After deleting, instead of issuing `cd /etc/apt`, I did `sudo rm - r /etc/apt` and now I've deleted it. I tried creating the `/etc/apt` directory again and running:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

This returns an error message as follows:

```
apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0: symbol _ZTI17pkgAcquireStatus2, version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
```

How do I restore my `/etc/apt` directory and fix `apt`?

Comment: `/etc/apt` should be a directory; `sudo rm /etc/apt` therefor shouldn't actually do anything other than print an error message.

Comment: Is this Debian, Ubuntu or Mint? You've tagged all three.

Comment: @derobert sorry I used `rm -r`

Comment: Ok — something else is also wrong with the system, as not having `/etc/apt` results in no errors, but some warnings like `W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)` (at least on Buster). I think the suggestion of reinstalling apt is a good place to start...

Comment: BTW: When you mistakenly `sudo rm -r /etc/apt`, were you trying to fix some other problem?

Comment: yes i was trying to delete `sources.list` and then instead `cd` I used the same `sudo rm -r`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Issue at Hand

You report that you have deleted `/etc/apt` while attempting to delete your `sources.list` file. Now you experience errors when attempting to use `apt`.

I have referenced [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306572/276845). Perhaps it can help you?

### Solution

First, see if you still have a copy of `apt`'s `.deb` file.

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Now look for a `.deb` with apt in its name, if you are running Debian Stretch on a 64-bit system it should be `apt_1.4.8_amd64.deb`. Use tab to autocomplete, or if not found you can download `apt` and its dependencies [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/apt).

After you have located the necessary package run as root(sudo) the following command:

```
dpkg -i apt_1.4.8_amd64.deb
```

This should reinstall the apt for you. You should now be able to run `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` as expected. Remember if you need to recreate your `sources.list` file you should [follow this example](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list).

The error about missing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0` should be solved if not you can install the lib from [here](https://packages.debian.org/stable/libs/libapt-pkg5.0).

Then you need to copy the library file into /usr/lib and run this command as root(sudo):

```
ldconfig -n -v /usr/lib
```

This [post may help too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25770/how-to-reinstall-apt-on-debian).

### Conclusion

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through each link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer I haven't yet tried it out! I'll update!

Comment: I found this solution to work for me: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/package-manager-apt-broken-after-upgrade